# ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr

Tags: boot, system-installation, wubi

So I downloaded the iso : ubuntu- 14.04.3 -desktop- amd64 in order to burn it to a USB key to this I used the pendrive
which allows me to burn the iso on my key . After that I opened the app Wubi to install ubuntu on my laptop .
After install and reboot , I can not seem to open ubuntu on my PC , he wrote me that there is an error on the file whose path is:

**/ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr**

I do the same steps on my computer and everything is working normally .... :( :( :(

I do not understand why my laptop it does not work ... I tried to reinstall it with other means
but the problem persists. And I do not want to erase Windows 10 to put ubuntu .

There is anyone who could help me please ???? :'(   ...

Answer (score 0):

Wubi does not work with Windows 8, 8.1, or 10.  You will have to install Ubuntu on its own partition. Instructions here:
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069)

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you use Windows in UEFI mode. If your Windows is installed in UEFI mode (=default mode for Windows 10), Microsoft has blocked the loading of non-UEFI or non-Windows bootloader from Windows boot menu. Same issue with tools like EasyBCD. See [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/#What_this_means). This means the bootloader of all official Wubi versions does not work.

You can use either a standard installation without Wubi (recommended - see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/386067) ) or community developed Wubi versions which support UEFI. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na).

I use Windows in UEFI mode, a recommended standard Ubuntu installation and a Wubi installed Ubuntu on the same machine. All works without problems. After installation all bootloaders are available in the UEFI menu of your machine.